# Problems with handson-ml-master notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am starting to read “Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow” and to use Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda to work on the handson-ml-master notebooks.  I followed the GitHub ageron/handson-ml installation instructions to install the environment (mlbook) on my Mac using Python3.5.  During the 2nd installation step, I received an error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.

To initialize your shell, run 
$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

Currently supported shells are:
    - bash
    - fish
    - tcsh
    - xonsh
    - zsh
    - powershell

because I normally use ksh.  So I executed bash, executed ,  and re-executed the command.  I received the same error, so I exited Terminal and tried from ksh, i.e. executed , re-executed the command,  and I received the same error.  So, I just proceeded with the 3rd and 4th installation steps without errors.

I ran Anaconda Navigator, launched Jupyter Notebook, navigated to handson-ml-master notebooks, and loaded Chapter 1 (01_the_machine_learning_landscape).  Running the 1st cell produces an error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-d884c8330a3b>", line 1
    **Chapter 1 – The Machine Learning landscape**
     ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Running the 2nd code cell produces nothing because I am using Python3.5, but running the 3rd code cell produces another error:

  File "<ipython-input-3-7dc69e9611c0>", line 31
    import warningsexit()
                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, running “Run All Below: does generate all of the graphs and successfully executes all but one data/graph generation cell, In[29], providing the errors:

```
  Saving figure overfitting_model_plot
  /Users/<user>/anaconda3/envs/mlbook/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:116: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
    x = um.multiply(x, x, out=x)
  /Users/<user>/anaconda3/envs/mlbook/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:117: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in reduce
    ret = umr_sum(x, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
```

Now I am wondering why my installation and running the code in the notebook seems to be having problems.  Any help would be appreciated, so I can move on to the remainder of the Notebook items.

Comment: Could you post which is line # 1 and #31?

Comment: NOTE: I believe I resolved the Jupyter Notebook issues, so posting those cells should not be necessary!

OK, most of my Jupyter Notebook execution questions were the result of my ignorance about Jupyter Notebooks. I discovered that when you load a notebook, the notebook apparently executes a Run All. Thus, rerunning cells may tend to create errors. Novice mistake!!!  See my next comment for still unresolved issue.

Comment: What I still need to understand are the installation errors.  I am still curious about the GitHub Notebook installation problems, i.e. activate error and my subsequent attempts to solve it with <conda init bash>, also producing errors.

Your help is greatly appreciated. I should point out that I am an Anaconda and a Python novice too and have only used Anaconda Spyder3 to start working with Python and to figure out how to load a “large” data set.

Comment: Thank you for update. I am working through this book too, however I did not follow Jupyter Notebook setup discussed in Ch.2. My setup (without using isolated environment) is: (1) installed Anaconda; (2) `$conda update conda`, (3) `$jupyter notebook` to open it in browser, (4) Then locate the path to files from the Jupyter Notebook `Files` tab. I tried to reproduce your error but was unsuccessful. In this setup I do not have to initialize the conda environment. If you do have a conda environment, I would think that all the packages would have to be installed in that environment.

Comment: I did go to GitHub and download the handson-ml.zip file, unzipped it into the mlbook environment created during the installation, and am using the notebooks in that environment. While things seem to be working, I am concerned that the installation error may jump up and bite me in the future. I have been retired for over 10 yrs. and have not done any S/W development, architecture, coding, etc. during that time. I decided that I needed to get my brain back in the game. Learning ML, beyond what I  did 10+ yrs. ago, and Python seemed like a good mechanism, so I am a novice in this respect. Regards

Comment: Okay, got it. Yes, this seems like a good book to learn ML with Python. Sorry I could not be of much help.